# Include setters in objects - only used in unit tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, setter

I have a question... Is it bad practice to add setters for variables in an object, if these setters are only used in the unit tests? I have a project where I have some objects that are initialized through parsing a json file with jackson. In the unit tests I've called the setters for the variables instead of always providing a json file. If I parse the json file for each test, this is a bit unnecessary overlay, since I only want to test that the specific objects behave as expected for given values.

Comment: Make them package-accessible (make sure your tests are in the same package), and then they are not part of the contract, but you can use them for testing.

Comment: Hint: text reads better when you use that thing called "vertical spacing", also known as linebreaks/paragraphs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is a bad practice. It's not earth shatteringly bad and sometimes it's the best available option, but still it's bad. In your case the root of the problem i having a state which is private to Java and public to some external JSON files (which could be the lesser of two evils in your case, but does not sound right)

A couple of alternatives (also bad, but in some contexts - maybe bit better) would be:

- make the required fields package-private and access them directly in your tests
- add a constructor to be used only in tests
- DO parse the JSON file for every test; you are not likely to notice any overhead.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I read a bit about it, and since Jackson uses reflection if the Java objects don't have annotations, I decided to instead add setters with jackson annotation so that these are used instead. This also makes it easier for me to test the way I want. I hope this perhaps is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a better option is to use mocking for this. If you can supply an interface to the values you would have extracted from the file, then you can mock that interface to return your test values.

If you are not familiar with mocking then perhaps you could supply an example.

Comment: mocking of value objects is considered anti-pattern. Mocking is meant to mock behavior. Much better alternative is given below (package-level fields, another constructor for test). I use this strategy extensively in my projects.